# Creating a function that is a friend to multiple classes

Tags: c++, friend-function

In the code below, I am trying to create a function "patient_count" that is a friend to the classes "horse" , "pig" , and "dog". I can get the function to be a friend with 1 class but not to all 3. Can anyone tell me what my mistake is?

```
/*******************************************************\
* Veternarian Class Problem - I need a class for each   *
* of 3 animals. Horse, Pig and Dogs                     *
\*******************************************************/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int HORSE_KENNEL = 100; // Number of horses we can store
const int PIG_KENNEL = 100; // Number of Pigs we can store
const int DOG_KENNEL = 100; // Number of Dogs we can store

/*******************************************************\
* Class horse                                           *
*                                                       *
* Member functions                                      *
* horse_count -- Keeps track of the number of horses    *
* add_horse -- Sends data into the object               *
* next_horse -- returns data from the object            *
\*******************************************************/

// Definition of the Class
class horse {

   private:
      int horse_count;              // Variable to keep track of data
      std::string horse_data[HORSE_KENNEL]; // A Place to put the data

      // Declarations for the method Prototypes
   public:            
      // Initialize 
      horse( );

      // A Function that accepts an argument but returns nothing
      void add_horse(const std::string new_horse_data);

      // This method returns the next Horse in the queue
      std::string next_horse( );

      friend int patient_count(horse);

};


/*******************************************************\
* Method Definition - Here we flush out the prototypes  *
* outlined in the last section                          *
\*******************************************************/
inline horse::horse( )
{
   for(int i = 0; i < HORSE_KENNEL; ++i){
      horse_data[i] = "Empty Spot";
   }
   horse_count = 0; // Zero the data count
}

/*******************************************************\
* horse::add_horse -- Send data to Object               *
\*******************************************************/
inline void horse::add_horse(const std::string new_horse_data)
{
   horse_data[horse_count] = new_horse_data;
   ++horse_count;
}

/*******************************************************\
* horse::next_horse - get data from object              *
\*******************************************************/

inline std::string horse::next_horse( )
{
   // this is specifically implementing a queue
   std::string current_horse = " ";
   int target_horse = 0;
   for(int i = 0;i < HORSE_KENNEL; ++i){
      if(horse_data[i] != "Empty Spot"){
         std::cout << "Horse Number " << i << " " << horse_data[i] << std::endl; 
      }
   }
   std::cout << "Select the horse you want: "; 
   std::cin >> target_horse;

   return (horse_data[target_horse]);
}

/*******************************************************\
* Class Pig                                             *
*                                                       *
* Member functions                                      *
* pig_count -- Keeps track of the number of pigs        *
* add_pig -- Sends data into the object                 *
* next_pig -- returns data from the object              *
\*******************************************************/

// Definition of the Class
class pig {

   private:
      int pig_count;              // Variable to keep track of data
      std::string pig_data[PIG_KENNEL]; // A Place to put the data

      // Declarations for the method Prototypes
   public:            
      // Initialize 
      pig( );

      // A Function that accepts an argument but returns nothing
      void add_pig(const std::string new_pig_data);

      // This method returns the next pig in the queue
      std::string next_pig( );

      friend pig patient_count(pig);
};


/*******************************************************\
* Method Definition - Here we flush out the prototypes  *
* outlined in the last section                          *
\*******************************************************/
inline pig::pig( )
{
   for(int i = 0; i < PIG_KENNEL; ++i){
      pig_data[i] = "Empty Spot";
   }
   pig_count = 0; // Zero the data count
}

/*******************************************************\
* pig::add_pig -- Send data to Object                   *
\*******************************************************/
inline void pig::add_pig(const std::string new_pig_data)
{
   pig_data[pig_count] = new_pig_data;
   ++pig_count;
}

/*******************************************************\
* pig::next_pig - get data from object                  *
\*******************************************************/

inline std::string pig::next_pig( )
{
   // this is specifically implementing a queue
   std::string current_pig = " ";
   int target_pig = 0;
   for(int i = 0;i < PIG_KENNEL; ++i){
      if(pig_data[i] != "Empty Spot"){
         std::cout << "pig Number " << i << " " << pig_data[i] << std::endl; 
      }
   }
   std::cout << "Select the pig you want: "; 
   std::cin >> target_pig;

   return (pig_data[target_pig]);
}

/*******************************************************\
* Class dog                                             *
*                                                       *
* Member functions                                      *
* dog_count -- Keeps track of the number of dogs        *
* data_to_object -- Sends data into the object          *
* data_from_object -- returns data from the object      *
\*******************************************************/

// Definition of the Class
class dog {

  private:
    int dog_count;              // Variable to keep track of data
    std::string dog_data[DOG_KENNEL]; // A Place to put the data

  // Declarations for the method Prototypes
  public:            
    // Initialize 
    dog( );

    // A Function that accepts an argument but returns nothing
    void add_dog(const std::string new_dog_data);

    // This method returns the next dog in the queue
    std::string next_dog( );

  friend dog patient_count(dog);
};


/*******************************************************\
* Method Definition - Here we flush out the prototypes  *
* outlined in the last section                          *
\*******************************************************/
inline dog::dog( )
{
   for(int i = 0; i < DOG_KENNEL; ++i){
      dog_data[i] = "Empty Spot";
   }
   dog_count = 0; // Zero the data count
}

/*******************************************************\
* dog::add_dog -- Send data to Object                   *
\*******************************************************/
inline void dog::add_dog(const std::string new_dog_data)
{
   dog_data[dog_count] = new_dog_data;
   ++dog_count;
}

/*******************************************************\
* dog::next_dog - get data from object                  *
\*******************************************************/

inline std::string dog::next_dog( )
{
   // this is specifically implementing a queue
   std::string current_dog = " ";
   int target_dog = 0;
   for(int i = 0;i < DOG_KENNEL; ++i){
      if(dog_data[i] != "Empty Spot"){
         std::cout << "dog Number " << i << " " << dog_data[i] << std::endl; 
      }
   }
   std::cout << "Select the dog you want: "; 
   std::cin >> target_dog;

   return (dog_data[target_dog]);
}

/**************************************************\
* This function is a friend of all the animal      *
* classes and returns the total of all animals     *
* PROBLEM ******* PROBLEM *********PROBLEM *********
* When I add the other 2 classes on the next line  *
* The program stops working                        *
\**************************************************/
// int patient_count(horse target_horse) //works
int patient_count(horse target_horse, pig target_pig, dog target_dog) // Nova
{
   //  int all_animals = target_horse.horse_count; //Works
   int all_animals = target_horse.horse_count + target_pig.pig_count + target_dog.dog_count; // Nova

   return (all_animals);
}
/**************************************************\
* The Class is defined above, this section is a    *
* Small testing harness to verify that the class   *
* is doing what it was designed to do              *
\**************************************************/
int main( )
{
   int total_animals;
   horse current_horse; // Create a instance

   // Send 3 values to the object
   current_horse.add_horse("Mr Ed, 10, Male");
   current_horse.add_horse("Lightning, 4, Female");
   current_horse.add_horse("Blitz, 7, Male");

   // Call for the return of the 3 values
   std::cout << "Selected Horse  ->" << current_horse.next_horse( ) << '\n';

   pig current_pig; // Create a instance

   // Send 3 values to the object
   current_pig.add_pig("Arnold, 4, Male");
   current_pig.add_pig("Babe, 2, Female");
   current_pig.add_pig("Killer, 7, Male");

   // Call for the return of the 3 values
   std::cout << "Selected Pig  ->" << current_pig.next_pig( ) << '\n';

   dog current_dog; // Create a instance

   // Send 3 values to the object
   current_dog.add_dog("Misty, 15, Female");
   current_dog.add_dog("Tristian, 12, Male");
   current_dog.add_dog("Tempest, 11, Female");

   // Call for the return of the 3 values
   std::cout << "Selected Dog  ->" << current_dog.next_dog( ) << '\n';


   // Now get the results from the friend function
   //  total_animals = patient_count(current_horse); // Works
   total_animals = patient_count(current_horse, current_pig, current_dog); // Nova
   std::cout << "Total Animals: " << total_animals << std::endl;
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Way to write a **minimal example**!

I think your function signatures don't match in your `friend` declarations.

Comment: @Kerrek: was that sarcasm, irony, or praise?

Comment: @Sehe: An effort to make future questions more palatable while at once having some fun :-)

Comment: @Nico: You could probably do better with a virtual function somewhere. Usually if you find yourself saying `friend` a lot, something isn't quite right.

Comment: Look on the bright side.. now you have a free animal kennel implementation...

Comment: @Nicole: Oh, by the way... is this homework?  You don't give a whole lot of context, so at least my personal inclination is to overdesign an answer.  That might not really be appropriate if the homework assignment is driving you toward a particular solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...I think there's a *lot* easier way to handle this:

```
class animal { 
    static int count;

    animal() { ++count; }
    ~animal() { --count; }
};

class horse : public animal { 
    // horse stuff
};

class pig : public animal { 
    // pig stuff here
};

class dog : public animal { 
    // dog stuff here
};

int patient_count() { return animal::count; }
```

Other than that, your code seems to have a fairly basic problem: it's confusing (for example) an animal with a collection of animals. You have a number of things like:

```
dog current_dog; // Create a instance

// Send 3 values to the object
current_dog.add_dog("Misty, 15, Female");
current_dog.add_dog("Tristian, 12, Male");
current_dog.add_dog("Tempest, 11, Female");
```

This makes no sense. A dog should represent exactly that: one dog. It has one name, one age, one sex, and so on. What you have above is really three dogs, not one. To represent them, you should have a collection of dogs -- preferably a standard collection like `std::vector`, but if you're not allowed to use that (which may be semi-reasonable, since this sounds/seems like homework) at least an array.

```
dog dogs[10];   // an array of 10 dogs (none yet initialized though)

dogs[0] = dog("Misty, 15, female");
dogs[1] = dog("Tristian, 12, male");
dogs[2] = dog("Tempest, 11, female");
```

Pigs, cows, horses, etc., are pretty much the same: one animal object should represent one actual animal. A collection of animals is a different thing from a single animal. Note, however, the comment above: an array of 10 dogs is exactly that -- 10 dogs (even though none of them has a name, age or sex yet, we've defined them so they all officially exist). This means the `patient_count` will report the existence of 10 dogs when you define the array, regardless of the number that contain meaningful data. This is one way in which `std::vector` is clearly a better choice. If you do something like:

```
std::vector<dog> dogs;

dogs.push_back("Misty, 15, female");
dogs.push_back("Tristian, 12, male");
dogs.push_back("Tempest, 11, female");
```

At this point, you've created and stored 3 dogs, so if you print out `patient_count` at this point, it should show 3 (representing actual dogs created/defined) not 10 (or whatever) to represent the number of *potential* animals, while ignoring the number that contain meaningful data.

Comment: Upvoting because you explain the dog/collection-of-dog issue with OP's code, but your `count()` is going to be giving some pretty inconsistent answers depending on how many temporary instances of dogs/pigs/horses happen to be live when you ask for the count.

Comment: @Lambdageek: I'm not sure "inconsistent" is the word I'd use -- you're certainly right that the number of objects at a given point in time may not match the number the user thinks s/he has created. At the same time, what it reports *should* be consistent with the number that actually exist.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am working on the solution now, I will comment on which one I can make work. BTW I tried the overloading solution before I asked the question. I created 3 versions of the function each expecting to be passed a structure from a different class. I like the Sub classing solution right now the best it seems the most logical, I will try it first.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define appropriate friend function `patient_count` with appropriate signatures/declaration as you declare them for each of the classes.

Right now you have one `patient_count` function defined with signature:

```
int patient_count(horse target_horse, pig target_pig, dog target_dog);
```

The friend functions declared in your various classes are with signatures:

```
dog patient_count(dog);
int patient_count(horse);
pig patient_count(pig);
```

You need to define functions for each of these signatures. 
The function you defined with 3 input parameters is pretty much useless because it is not declared are friend of any of your classes.

Note that in C++, functions are overloaded(each function has separate existance) based on:

- No of Arguments
- Sequence of Arguments &
- Type o Arguments

So each of those functions are separate and not the same and need a separate definition.

Answer (score 1):

In your classes, you declared them as friends of the following 3 functions(for the horse, pig, and dog class respectively)

```
int patient_count(horse);
pig patient_count(pig);
dog patient_count(dog);
```

None of those functions exist.  The only function that exists is this one:

```
int patient_count(horse,pig,dog);
```

Replace your friend line in each of your classes with that declaration.  You will need to forward declare pig and dog also.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
int patient_count(horse);
pig patient_count(pig);
dog patient_count(dog);
```

and

```
int patient_count(horse target_horse, pig target_pig, dog target_dog);
```

Are **overloads** for patient_count. The best thing would to create a base class animal with field animal_count like this

```
/*******************************************************\
* Veternarian Class Problem - I need a class for each   *
* of 3 animals. Horse, Pig and Dogs                     *
\*******************************************************/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int HORSE_KENNEL = 100; // Number of horses we can store
const int PIG_KENNEL = 100; // Number of Pigs we can store
const int DOG_KENNEL = 100; // Number of Dogs we can store


class animal{
protected:
    int animal_count;
public:
    friend int patient_count(animal);
};



/*******************************************************\
* Class horse                                           *
*                                                       *
* Member functions                                      *
* animal_count -- Keeps track of the number of horses    *
* add_horse -- Sends data into the object               *
* next_horse -- returns data from the object            *
\*******************************************************/
// Definition of the Class
class horse : public animal {

  private:
    std::string horse_data[HORSE_KENNEL]; // A Place to put the data

  // Declarations for the method Prototypes
  public:            
    // Initialize 
    horse::horse( );

    // A Function that accepts an argument but returns nothing
    void add_horse(const std::string new_horse_data);

    // This method returns the next Horse in the queue
    std::string next_horse( );


};


/*******************************************************\
* Method Definition - Here we flush out the prototypes  *
* outlined in the last section                          *
\*******************************************************/
inline horse::horse( )
{
  for(int i = 0; i < HORSE_KENNEL; ++i){
    horse_data[i] = "Empty Spot";
  }
  animal_count = 0; // Zero the data count
}

/*******************************************************\
* horse::add_horse -- Send data to Object               *
\*******************************************************/
inline void horse::add_horse(const std::string new_horse_data)
{
  horse_data[animal_count] = new_horse_data;
  ++animal_count;
}

/*******************************************************\
* horse::next_horse - get data from object              *
\*******************************************************/

inline std::string horse::next_horse( )
{
  // this is specifically implementing a queue
  std::string current_horse = " ";
  int target_horse = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i < HORSE_KENNEL; ++i){
    if(horse_data[i] != "Empty Spot"){
      std::cout << "Horse Number " << i << " " << horse_data[i] << std::endl; 
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Select the horse you want: "; 
  std::cin >> target_horse;

return (horse_data[target_horse]);
}

/*******************************************************\
* Class Pig                                             *
*                                                       *
* Member functions                                      *
* animal_count -- Keeps track of the number of pigs        *
* add_pig -- Sends data into the object                 *
* next_pig -- returns data from the object              *
\*******************************************************/

// Definition of the Class
class pig :public animal{

  private:
     // Variable to keep track of data
    std::string pig_data[PIG_KENNEL]; // A Place to put the data

  // Declarations for the method Prototypes
  public:            
    // Initialize 
    pig::pig( );

    // A Function that accepts an argument but returns nothing
    void add_pig(const std::string new_pig_data);

    // This method returns the next pig in the queue
    std::string next_pig( );
};


/*******************************************************\
* Method Definition - Here we flush out the prototypes  *
* outlined in the last section                          *
\*******************************************************/
inline pig::pig( )
{
  for(int i = 0; i < PIG_KENNEL; ++i){
    pig_data[i] = "Empty Spot";
  }
  animal_count = 0; // Zero the data count
}

/*******************************************************\
* pig::add_pig -- Send data to Object                   *
\*******************************************************/
inline void pig::add_pig(const std::string new_pig_data)
{
  pig_data[animal_count] = new_pig_data;
  ++animal_count;
}

/*******************************************************\
* pig::next_pig - get data from object                  *
\*******************************************************/

inline std::string pig::next_pig( )
{
  // this is specifically implementing a queue
  std::string current_pig = " ";
  int target_pig = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i < PIG_KENNEL; ++i){
    if(pig_data[i] != "Empty Spot"){
      std::cout << "pig Number " << i << " " << pig_data[i] << std::endl; 
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Select the pig you want: "; 
  std::cin >> target_pig;

return (pig_data[target_pig]);
}

/*******************************************************\
* Class dog                                             *
*                                                       *
* Member functions                                      *
* animal_count -- Keeps track of the number of dogs        *
* data_to_object -- Sends data into the object          *
* data_from_object -- returns data from the object      *
\*******************************************************/

// Definition of the Class
class dog :public animal {

  private:
    std::string dog_data[DOG_KENNEL]; // A Place to put the data

  // Declarations for the method Prototypes
  public:            
    // Initialize 
    dog::dog( );

    // A Function that accepts an argument but returns nothing
    void add_dog(const std::string new_dog_data);

    // This method returns the next dog in the queue
    std::string next_dog( );


};


/*******************************************************\
* Method Definition - Here we flush out the prototypes  *
* outlined in the last section                          *
\*******************************************************/
inline dog::dog( )
{
  for(int i = 0; i < DOG_KENNEL; ++i){
    dog_data[i] = "Empty Spot";
  }
  animal_count = 0; // Zero the data count
}

/*******************************************************\
* dog::add_dog -- Send data to Object                   *
\*******************************************************/
inline void dog::add_dog(const std::string new_dog_data)
{
  dog_data[animal_count] = new_dog_data;
  ++animal_count;
}

/*******************************************************\
* dog::next_dog - get data from object                  *
\*******************************************************/

inline std::string dog::next_dog( )
{
  // this is specifically implementing a queue
  std::string current_dog = " ";
  int target_dog = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i < DOG_KENNEL; ++i){
    if(dog_data[i] != "Empty Spot"){
      std::cout << "dog Number " << i << " " << dog_data[i] << std::endl; 
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Select the dog you want: "; 
  std::cin >> target_dog;

return (dog_data[target_dog]);
}

/**************************************************\
* This function is a friend of all the animal      *
* classes and returns the total of all animals     *
* PROBLEM ******* PROBLEM *********PROBLEM *********
* When I add the other 2 classes on the next line  *
* The program stops working                        *
\**************************************************/
// int patient_count(horse target_horse) //works
int patient_count(animal target_animal) // Nova
{
    int all_animals = target_animal.animal_count;
    return (all_animals);
}
int patient_count(horse target_horse, pig target_pig, dog target_dog) // Nova
{
//  int all_animals = target_horse.animal_count; //Works
   int all_animals = patient_count(target_horse) + patient_count(target_pig) + patient_count(target_dog); // Nova

return (all_animals);
}
/**************************************************\
* The Class is defined above, this section is a    *
* Small testing harness to verify that the class   *
* is doing what it was designed to do              *
\**************************************************/
int main( )
{
  int total_animals;
  horse current_horse; // Create a instance

  // Send 3 values to the object
  current_horse.add_horse("Mr Ed, 10, Male");
  current_horse.add_horse("Lightning, 4, Female");
  current_horse.add_horse("Blitz, 7, Male");

  // Call for the return of the 3 values
  std::cout << "Selected Horse  ->" << current_horse.next_horse( ) << '\n';

  pig current_pig; // Create a instance

  // Send 3 values to the object
  current_pig.add_pig("Arnold, 4, Male");
  current_pig.add_pig("Babe, 2, Female");
  current_pig.add_pig("Killer, 7, Male");

  // Call for the return of the 3 values
  std::cout << "Selected Pig  ->" << current_pig.next_pig( ) << '\n';

  dog current_dog; // Create a instance

  // Send 3 values to the object
  current_dog.add_dog("Misty, 15, Female");
  current_dog.add_dog("Tristian, 12, Male");
  current_dog.add_dog("Tempest, 11, Female");

  // Call for the return of the 3 values
  std::cout << "Selected Dog  ->" << current_dog.next_dog( ) << '\n';


  // Now get the results from the friend function
//  total_animals = patient_count(current_horse); // Works
  total_animals = patient_count(current_horse, current_pig, current_dog); // Nova
  std::cout << "Total Animals: " << total_animals << std::endl;
return (0);
}
```